An inequality related to Problem 10210 AMM 1992 No. 3
Problem. Let $A$ be a $N \times N$ real matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $a_{ij} \ge 0, \forall i, j$. Let $1$ denote $N\times 1$ all-ones vector. Prove that
$$N^2 1^\top A^\top A A^\top 1 \ge (1^\top A 1)^3. $$
This problem was asked by @Pavel Gubkin in math stackexchange without an answer.
It is related to Problem 10210 in AMM 1992 No. 3:
(a) Let $f$ be a continuous non-negative real-valued function defined on the squares $[0, 1]^2$. Show that
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x_1, y_1)f(x_2, y_1)f(x_1, y_2)\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dy_1\,dy_2$$
$$\ge \left(\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)\,dx\,dy\right)^3.$$
See: The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 99, No. 3 (Mar., 1992), pp. 265-266.
I tried to seek the official solution, but failed.

Do you know how to prove No 3 (a)?

@mathworker21 No. Any solutions are welcome.

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189222/cauchy-schwarz-proof-of-sidorenko-for-3-edge-path-blakley-roy-inequality for the integral inequality. The discrete one might be a particular case, not sure (no time to check).

@darijgrinberg Thanks. Yes, the discrete case is addressed in the accepted answer for that question.
